# Tkinter: Trying to get a checklist that strikeouts labels and sends them to the bottom of the list, but it fails after the first one

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m trying to figure out how to create checklists of arbitrary length that will allow any checkbutton, once ticked, will cross off the corresponding label and send the ticked box and label to the bottom of the list.

So far, I can create the checkbuttons and make the corresponding labels strikeout. However, I’m having a lot of trouble with getting the items sent to the bottom. Getting the first item to do is easy enough, but when the checklist gets shuffled it no longer works.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, IntVar, Frame

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        self.normal_Font = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, overstrike = 0)
        self.strike_Font = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, overstrike = 1)

        self.popup = Popup(self)


    '''When a checkbutton is checked, change the label to strikethrough and move it and
    the checkbox to the bottom (if unchecked). If checked, remove strikethrough.'''           



    def check_off(self, num):                 

            #Check if the IntVar for this checkbutton is equal to the on-value.

            if self.popup.button_vars[num].get() == 1:
                #This is where it doesn't work, because the labels are no longer in the same order.
                self.popup.checklist_labels[num]['font'] = self.strike_Font

                #Append the new label to the list of labels, then delete the old one.

                self.popup.checklist_labels.append(self.popup.checklist_labels[num])
                del self.popup.checklist_labels[num]

                #Re-do the grid with the new order

                for i, item in enumerate(self.popup.checklist_labels):
                    item.grid(column = 1, row = 1 + i)

                #Same for checkbuttons. 

                self.popup.checkbuttons.append(self.popup.checkbuttons[num])
                del self.popup.checkbuttons[num]

                for i, item in enumerate(self.popup.checkbuttons):
                    #item["command"] = lambda i=i: self.check_off(i)
                    item.grid(column = 0, row = 1 + i) 

            else:

                #If unticked, turn the font back to normal, but keep it in its position.
                self.popup.checklist_labels[num]['font'] = self.normal_Font

class Popup(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, controller):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,controller)

        self.controller = controller     


        self.checklist_labels = []
        self.checkbuttons = []
        self.button_vars = []


        #In the full version, these are created with the press of a button        
        self.checklist_details = ["A", "B", "C"]

        '''For each item in the checklist, create an IntVar, checkbuttons, labels for the checklists
       (checkbutton text can't be struckthrough) and grid them''' 

        for i, item in enumerate(self.checklist_details):

            self.button_vars.append(IntVar())
            self.checkbuttons.append(ttk.Checkbutton(self, variable = self.button_vars[-1],
              onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda i=i: controller.check_off(i)))
            self.checklist_labels.append(ttk.Label(self, text = item, font = controller.normal_Font))

            self.checkbuttons[i].grid(column = 0, row = i+1)
            self.checklist_labels[i].grid(column = 1, row = i+1)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I think the crux of the issue is here:

```
                if self.popup.button_vars[num].get() == 1:
                #This is where it doesn't work, because the labels are no longer in the same order.
                self.popup.checklist_labels[num]['font'] = self.strike_Font
```

Suppose I had buttons A, B and C. If I press B, then the method will correctly determine that the corresponding IntVar() (self.popup.button_vars[1]) == 1, and correctly shuffle self.popup.checklist_labels[1] and self.popup_checkbuttons[1], which correspond to "B".

However, after the order is shuffled to ["A", "C", "B"], clicking the "C" button will not work as intended, as clicking "C" will correctly reference self.popup.button_vars[2], but self.popup.checklist_labels[2] will now reference "B".

How could I fix this? Should I apply a small change, or completely alter my approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to manage the information you need for this application. Here is an example of how to use the grid geometry manager to keep track of the order  for you. You really don't need the lists. You also don't need the labels, if you switch to tk.checkbuttons, which have a font attribute (instead of ttk.checkbuttons).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, IntVar, Frame

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        self.normal_Font = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, overstrike = 0)
        self.strike_Font = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, overstrike = 1)

        self.popup = Popup(self)


    '''When a checkbutton is checked, change the label to strikethrough and move it and
    the checkbox to the bottom (if unchecked). If checked, remove strikethrough.'''           



    def check_off(self, num):                 

        # If the checkbutton is NOT checked, change the font, but don't sort.
        if self.popup.button_vars[num].get() == 0:
            self.popup.checkbuttons[num]['font'] = self.normal_Font
            # Leave positions where they are (don't sort)
            return


        # Strikeout font.
        self.popup.checkbuttons[num]['font'] = self.strike_Font
        current_row = self.popup.checkbuttons[num].grid_info()['row']
        if current_row == len(self.popup.checkbuttons):
            # Already at the bottom. No movement required.
            return

        # Temporarily remove this checkbutton so it is not gridded.
        self.popup.checkbuttons[num].grid_remove()

        # Sort the remaining checkbuttons. Note that the grid_slaves
        # function returns slaves in the most recent grid order. This
        # means that [num] checkbutton is returned first in the list.
        order = {}
        for child in self.popup.grid_slaves():
            # Key is the sequence/index, value is the widget object.
            order[child.grid_info()['row']] = child

        for index,old_row in enumerate(sorted(order.keys())):
            order[old_row].grid(row=index + 1)
            print(order[old_row]['text'],index + 1)

        # Finally, regrid the checkbutton we removed earlier to the bottom.
        self.popup.checkbuttons[num].grid(row=len(self.popup.checkbuttons))


class Popup(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, controller):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,controller)

        self.controller = controller     


        #self.checklist_labels = []
        self.checkbuttons = []
        self.button_vars = []


        #In the full version, these are created with the press of a button        
        self.checklist_details = ["A", "B", "C"]

        '''For each item in the checklist, create an IntVar, checkbuttons, labels for the checklists
       (checkbutton text can't be struckthrough) and grid them'''
        # Well, ttk.checkbuttons require themes to change their fonts, but tk.checkbuttons don't.
        # But in either case, you CAN change their font attributes.

        for i, item in enumerate(self.checklist_details):

            self.button_vars.append(IntVar())
            self.checkbuttons.append(tk.Checkbutton(self, variable = self.button_vars[i],
              onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda i=i: controller.check_off(i),
              text = item, font = controller.normal_Font))

            self.checkbuttons[i].grid(column = 0, row = i+1)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! However, while this works for the stripped-down example, in practice I'm going to have other widgets in the same grid. Is there a way to avoid them getting in the way, without having to temporarily remove and add them back to the grid every time?

Comment: That is an entirely different question. And depending on what your requirements are for additional widgets, it's quite possible that you will need a different strategy for managing these checkbuttons. One way to keep things together, as well as separated from other GUI elements is to use frames to organize things. But not knowing what additional requirements you may have, it's not practical to recommend a strategy that may (or not) work.

Comment: I've found: as "grid_slaves()"  produces a list, I simply need to determine where the checkbuttons will appear in that list. For instance, changing line 45 to "for child in self.detail_popup.grid_slaves()[0:len(self.detail_popup.checkbuttons) -1]:" will work if there are widgets above (but not below) the checkbuttons.